# App Sync Resolver to sort by Timestamp in Ascending Order

Tags: aws-appsync

I have a GSI which has a hash key of userid and a sort key of created. The hash key is a GUID and the sort key is a ISO timestamp assigned by my mapping template when an entity is created.

I want to be able to pass in a userid and get a list all entities ordered by my recent timestamp.

There is also the complication of pagenated responses. I would like the sorting to happen before.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 4):

AWS AppSync allow you to specify `scanIndexForward` as a property in the [request mapping template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-query). You can specify true (ascending) or false (descending) traversal of the index based on the sort key. Using the property you can order a time series data. You might want to consider storing your created information as a time in millis since epoch, rather than ISO 8601 string.